# How to increase the font size of the x and y axis for a heat map

Tags: python

How to increase the font size of the x and y axes for a heat map?

```
# Correlation between different variables
   corr = data_set.corr()
#
# Set up the matplotlib plot configuration
#
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(40, 20))
#
# Configure a custom diverging colormap
#
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(230, 20, as_cmap=True)
#
# Draw the heatmap
    sns.heatmap(corr, annot=True, cmap=cmap)
     ax.set_title('Correlation Heat Map', weight='bold', fontsize = 25)
sns.set(font_scale=3)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why not like you have done it?

Comment: The font is not increasing. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using bigger numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=20)
ax.set_yticklabels(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=20)
```

Comment: Thank you! Any idea how to increase the font size for the scale bar too?

Comment: scalebar = scalebar.ScaleBar(1, "m", font_size=20)
ax.add_artist(scalebar)

Comment: NameError: name 'scalebar' is not defined

Comment: Yeah, it's a separate package matplotlib_scalebar.  from matplotlib_scalebar import scalebar

Comment: Error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fontsize'. Trying to read here 
  https://pypi.org/project/matplotlib-scalebar/ but cannot seem to get the right result.